# Operations on 2 images (adding, subtraction etc. ), without using a buffer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, pylons

I want to know is there any way to make operations on two images without analyzing them pixel by pixel. I try to make a mix view from two cameras in real time. Becouse of that, operations must be made with speed 10 frames per second at least.

First version of my program looks like this:

```
                        CPylonImage im1;
                CPylonImage im2;

    uint32_t width = im2.GetWidth();
        uint32_t height = im2.GetHeight();
        uint8_t* buffer1 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im1.GetBuffer());
        uint8_t* p1 = buffer1;
        uint8_t* buffer2 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im2.GetBuffer());
        uint8_t* p2 = buffer2;
        for (uint32_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (uint32_t x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++p1)
            {
                *p2 = (uint8_t)*p1+*p2;
                ++p2;
            }
        }
        ShowImage( im2, "Mixed image");
```

But this was too slow.

I will be very grateful for any answer.

Comment: Please clarify.. your title says "without a buffer" but your question mentions "not pixel by pixel".. those are not mutually exclusive? What do you really want? What do you mean with "without a buffer"? How do you expect to subtract one image from another without doing that for each pixel?

Comment: You could try using SSE instructions to do it on 4 bytes at a time. But the real questions is: Have you profiled to know that tha bottleneck is on this specific action? What resolution are we talking about?

Comment: I added part of my previous code to clarify. Maybe i could add a buffer to whole image. How can I made it? The resolution of my camera is 1294 pixels x 964 pixels.

Comment: Program is compiling, but it brings me an exception after few seconds of running. The exception  is sth about access violation.

Comment: Use hardware acceleration, such as OpenGL or DirectX. SSE can help too. But I don't get the "without the buffer" thing.

Comment: I identified the bufforing with "pixel by pixel" action. What was, as I assume, a reasoning mistake.

Comment: @CherryCola Please understand that a *buffer* is just a memory region that stores pixels. `im1` and `im2` already have an internal buffer for this purpose, and when you do `uint8_t* buffer1 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im1.GetBuffer());` you are not creating a new buffer, you are just accessing the one that already exists and this is the efficient way to do it. The bottleneck of your application is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The code you shared has many problems and in the comment section you state that it doesn't even work. I think you should focus on solving one problem at a time, and when the code actually works then it makes sense to try to make it faster.

Your application retrieves the `width` from one image and the `height` from the other. This rarely leads to good things.

```
    uint32_t width = im1.GetWidth();
    uint32_t height = im2.GetHeight();
```

Alright, so `buffer1` points to `im1`, and `p1` points to `buffer1`. I think you don't really need `p1`, just use `buffer1` instead.

```
    uint8_t* buffer1 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im1.GetBuffer());
    uint8_t* p1 = buffer1;
```

And now `buffer2` and `p2` points to `im1`. **What?!** Shouldn't it be `im2`??? You don't really need `p2`.

```
    uint8_t* buffer2 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im1.GetBuffer());
    uint8_t* p2 = buffer2;


    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
```

The next loop increments `p`, which is a variable that wasn't declared. I suppose you tried to increment `p1`.

```
        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++p)
        {
            *p2 = (uint8_t)*p1+*p2;
            ++p2;
        }
    }
```

Right now it doesn't make sense to display `im2` since it wasn't modified by the code.

```
    ShowImage( im2, "Mixed image");
```

One more thing, if `im1` and `im2` have different sizes it could lead to a crash.

**I strongly suggest you take a look at the following post to know how to ask better questions and get people to help you:  [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)**

There is a few technologies that can speed up the processing of those arithmetic operations:

- If you have an Intel CPU: [Intel® Threading Building Blocks (Intel® TBB)](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/);
- If you have an Intel CPU: [Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives (Intel® IPP)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp);
- If you have a GPU that supports OpenGL, you can write your own [GLSL shader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language);
- If you have a GPU that supports DirectX, you can write your own [HLSL shader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);
- If you have an NVIDIA GPU: [CUDA™](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html);
- If you have an NVIDIA/ATI GPU: [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/);
- You can try [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), a C++ template library for linear algebra (performs optimized operations on matrices);
- [OpenMP®](http://openmp.org/wp/) (a specification for a set of compiler directives, library routines, and environment variables that can be used to specify high-level parallelism in Fortran and C/C++ programs);
- At last but not least, you can always write your own *assembly* code to perform the arithmetic operations.

Comment: I didn't add my actual code. Ijust tried to rebuild it on quickly from memory. As you can see i made some mistakes while doing it. Two images have same sizes. Anyway Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: OpenCV is a framework for computer vision that presents many image processing techniques, including the operations you are interested at. To speed up the processing, OpenCV uses several of the technologies above. It's worth checking it out since it's open source and you can take a look at the source code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start optimising, make sure that your output is correct!

The expression

```
*p2 = (uint8_t)*p1+*p2;
```

will overflow and give you wrong results. The cast `(uint8_t)` will not magically
clip your values to a valid range, but only convert your result of the addition.
In this case the cast does not do anything, since the operands are uint8_t.

```
const uint16_t a = *p1;
const uint16_t b = *p2;
const uint16_t sum = a+b;
*p2 = static_cast<uint8_t>( sum > 255 ? 255 : sum );
```

Better yet, add the results and divide by two, this way you stay in a valid range,
only loose the LSB and it's branchless.

```
*p2 = static_cast<uint8_t>( sum >> 1 );
```

Some more tips you could try before you have to use a different technique.

- Use a compiler (vc>=2012,gcc>=4.7) which supports Auto-Vectorisation and turn it on.
- If you are compiling for windows 32bit use "/arch:SSE2"
- Give the compilers hints by using `const` and `restrict`.
- if you are sure that the window size is always the same, use fixed width and height

e.g.

```
void add( const CPylonImage& im1, CPylonImage& im2 )
{
    const int w = 1294; //im1.width();
    const int h = 964; //im1.height();

    const uint8_t* restrict buffer1 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im1.getBuffer() );
    uint8_t* restrict buffer2 = static_cast<uint8_t*>( im2.getBuffer() );
    for( int i = 0; i < w*h; i++ )
    {
        const uint16_t a = buffer1[i];
        const uint16_t b = buffer2[i];
        const uint16_t sum = a+b >> 1;
        buffer2[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>( sum );
    }
}
```